# Reusable code to retrieve data

Tags: asp.net, database, code-reuse

i have found an very good method for retrieving any result set from the database just by specifying the stored procedure name.i think the code is very much reusable.code is as follows

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

private DataSet GetFreshData(string sprocName)
{
    using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection() )
    {
        using ( SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter() )
        {        
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText = sprocName;
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.SelectCommand.Connection = conn;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                da.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
                da.Fill(ds);
                da.SelectCommand.Connection.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                // do other things...calling Close() or Dispose() 
                // for SqlConnection or SqlDataAdapter objects not necessary
                // as its taken care of in the nested "using" statements
            }

            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

my question is can someone suggest a modification to this method when the stored procedure need to specify several parameters

Comment: I would suggest capture the output of the stored procedure too, put that into an object that can hold both the output and the dataset (in case there are any errors)

Comment: Yes the code is reusable, however when the stored procedure returns one value (a result of an aggregate function for instance), this maybe be overkill. So also have a `GetScalarData` or similar function and do a `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`. Also to execute a SP which doesn't return any value, have a `ExecuteSP` function which will do a `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: congrats!! you have reinvented the wheel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy! :) take a `SqlParameter[]` as the second argument to the function.

Then make sure `da.SelectCommand.Parameters` is filled with the list of `SqlParameter` objects in the `SqlParameter[]`

Comment: yep that's the simplest, isn't it? you can even make it default a new array with zero parameters